# Non-Awaited Thread just stops executing after api returns, is this a known bug, or can anyone explain what is happening?

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

If I have an api controller, and I want it to return to the user as quick as possible, while spinning off a thread to handle some more long running process I thought I could just not await the async method call like this.

```
DoSomeNonAwaitedAsyncThing(data);
var result = await DoSomeNormalAsyncThing(data);
return result;
```

But, the DoSomeNonAwaitedAsyncThing code will stop executing when the api controller returns(no exception or anything it just stops running).

If I change the signature of DoSomeNonAwaitedAsyncThing from async Task to **async void**, then the thread will run to completion, but it will also block the api call from returning until the non awaited task is complete.

also, if I change the way I call the method to this(below) then the method will run to completion rather than stopping half way through the method.

```
Task.Run(async () => { DoSomeNonAwaitedAsyncThing(data); });
```

I created a repo with a project to demonstrate the issue. https://github.com/JamesWebDev/AsyncThreadIssueExample

Also worth noting, I added this to the web config so that it should allow the api call to return while threads are still running.

```
<add key="aspnet:AllowAsyncDuringSyncStages" value="true"/>
```

Comment: It's a bug in the application code. Check [The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/). Scott Hansleman explains how to [properly run background tasks in ASP.NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx). That article was written back in 2014 though. .NET Core has explicit support for background services

Comment: `then the thread will run to completion, but it will also block the api call` that's not how `async/await` works. It won't do anything run in the background. `async` is only syntactic sugar that allows you to write `await` to await already asynchronous operations without blocking. If `DoSomeNonAwaitedAsyncThing` blocks, it means it's *not* asynchronous or that it executes a blocking operation before it starts its asynchronous work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I included an example repo so you can try it for your self. The api call will not return until the non-awaited async void method is complete. All the relavant code is here https://github.com/JamesWebDev/AsyncThreadIssueExample/blob/master/AsyncThreadExample/Controllers/ValuesController.cs and if you want to make fact that the api call has not returned extra obvious up the time in await Task.Delay(2000); to something like 10,000 so that it really stands out.

Comment: Stephen Cleary posted the same things I've said in the comments. His, and Scott Hanselman's articles were posted within a few months of each other in 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> DoSomeNonAwaitedAsyncThing code will stop executing when the api controller returns

Most likely, the problem is because `DoSomeNonAwaitedAsyncThing` is attempting to re-enter the ASP.NET Classic request context. By default, [`await` will capture the current context and resume on that context](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html); in ASP.NET Classic, this "context" is an ASP.NET Classic request context. However, since the request that that request context refers to has *already completed*, this can cause... complications.

The reason it works with `Task.Run` is because the current context for `DoSomeNonAwaitedAsyncThing` is no longer the ASP.NET Classic request context; it is now the thread pool context. And the thread pool is still there when the `await` inside `DoSomeNonAwaitedAsyncThing` is ready to continue.

As a best practice, you should [avoid fire-and-forget on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) (this is true both for Classic and Core). The proper solution is to have your controller write to a reliable queue (e.g., Azure Queue), and have an independent background process handle that operation (e.g., Azure Function). There are alternatives to the independent background process - `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` and `IRegisteredObject` for Classic, and `IHostedService` and `IHostApplicationLifetime` for Core - but the bottom line is that you at *least* need a reliable queue between your controller and background process. Otherwise you could lose work during a shutdown/recycle.